# How to feed data as shown as info using struct in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I want to restart with data structure ( and Ai + I want to clear all my misconceptions too. ;P )

For now I want to know how would I put given pictorial info into algorithm using C# structure. Image processing is not required here. Just need to feed the data in.

Here I need this question to be modified too if not clear. :|

Say Arad is a city in Romania from where I have to go to another city Bucharest.
This map also has info of how far all connecting cities are from any city.

How would I use these info in program to start with any searching or sorting algo?

Any pointer will be helpful. Say if this can be done using anything else than struct. Something like node or something. I don't know.

Please consider I want to learn things. So using C# for ease in use not to use its inbuilt searching and sorting functions. Later to confirm I might use.

[image: The cities of Romania to data struct]

Comment: homework? I saw the exact same (or real close) graph in my AI class. Look up breadth first search, uniform cost search, best first search and A*.

Comment: Yes it is the same one. ;P But not for solving the homework, honestly. Just want to learn it by better way by doing it by programming .. so need help. Better if I get the answer here after 16th. will prove, this question is not here for solving the homework, lol. Searching algos can be used only when when the algorithm knows the input info. This is where I m stuck .. b4 even implementing the algos. Or may be m heading wrong direction.

Comment: @Rahul2047, it would help to know what format your input data is in.  For example, you could create a text file with one line per path (e.g., 'Arad Sibiu 140' followed by 'Arad Zerind 75') as an easy way to start.  Then parse each line, separate the node names and the path length, and create a list of data structures as described in Eric' series.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you typically solve this problem is to create a node class and an edge class. Each node has a set of edges that have "lengths", and each edge connects two nodes. You then write a shortest-path algorithm that determines the least-total-length set of edges that connects two nodes.

For a brief tutorial on how to do that, see my series of articles on the `A*` algorithm:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/astar/

Comment: Hey, You are Eric Lippert from MS itself .. m definitely going to look into it. Thanks for answering my question here.

Comment: Well I am still concentrating on the input part not the solving part. How do we input the given data to the algorithm for this particular question? I need some time here.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not exactly what you're looking for, [Eric Lippert's series on graph colouring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/) is an excellent step-by-step example of designing data structures and implementing algorithms (efficiently!) in C#.  It has helped me a lot; I highly recommend reading it.  Once you've worked your way through that, you will know much more about C# and you will understand some of the specific design tradeoffs that you may encounter based on your specific problem, including what data structure to use for a particular problem.

If you just want to look at raw algorithms, the [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) has many algorithms defined for it over the years.  I would recommend implementing the common [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) first.  The Wikipedia article has pseudocode; with what you get out of Eric Lippert's series, you should be in good shape to develop an implementation of this.  If you still want more step-by-step guidance, try a [search for "Dijkstra's algorithm in C#"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Dijkstra%27s%20Algorithm%20in%20C#&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-26&form=QBRE).

Hope that helps!

Comment: will get back here ... Seems very similar and complex.. and m close to set this answer as my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link -- however, I note that my series on the A* algorithm is probably more germane to the specific problem. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/astar/